# Using MySQL to pull all rows and use Jquery to show next 25 and next 25, etc.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, wordpress

So the situation I have is I'm using Wordpress and I'm trying to write a custom plugin.

What I want to do is grab an array of all the posts and show the first 25.

Then underneath that I want to have a button that says , "Show Next 25" and when I hit the button it will add the next 25 to the list of articles, and if I hit again, wash , rinse repeat till it's out of articles.

I was going to write this in straight PHP / MySQL but not sure how to incorporate JQuery into it.

My thought was to write a series of offsetting MYSQL statements but thats probably too clunkly.

My 2nd thought was to pull all the post info into one Associative array and then find a way to parse the other output into the hidden divs.

Thoughts?

I tried looking for a wordpress plugin that does this but did not find one and I tried searching for a situation like this on here, found some stuff similar but not the same.

I guess you could compare this to commenting feature where it shows the last 10 commends and you have hit a button to see the rest of the comments.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: You should probably start by reading this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I guess the example that better fits is if you go LinkedIn and at the bottom is "Show More" and it expands out - sorry I didnt explain that up front. Reading comments now.

Answer (score 1):

I would grab from the database only 25 at a time.  Then I might use JQuery to do the ajax call to pull another 25 based on what has already been shown.

Use a limit 25, offset clause on the mysql.  Send the next offset value to the web page as a hidden input or a javascript var.  Then use JQuery ajax to call your php function that returns a JSON data of the next 25 rows to display.

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't JQuery, but I like this:
http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

But I also agree w/ the thoughts, you're wasting the resources of Ajax if you do it this way.  Ajax would do well here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how "I" would do it, though this is just a suggestion.

First, if you don't already have it, I would suggest something like [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) to code in.  It's free, but I have the pay for for very cheap (i think my last upgrade lic was 30 bucks?).  If you, buy just one copy, they'll offer you a ton of discounts if you ever decide not to upgrade.  Good program for HTML5/php editing.

Second, go look at [Codeigniter's Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).  After looking this page over, you'll see very easily why I would suggest CI.  CI's Active Record makes safe and secure SQL calls an absolute breeze, though for better security, I would suggest you make use of there [XML filter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) and never ["chain" Active Record calls](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#chaining) as it shows you can do on that page.

Finally, as I said before, I would read up on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), and [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) commands.  After a stirring read, I'd probably end up using [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to make calls to a controller containing a simple php active record function that would return the wanted update data at +25 "ahead" of what the user is actually looking at.